# Can a SSH reverse tunnel accept non-local connections?

Tags: ssh-tunneling, autossh

I have a server in my office behind a firewall, a home server behind NAT, and a laptop I carry around. Sometimes I want to reach the office server from home so I did the following setup.

Home router redirects port 2223 to homeserver port 22.

I am running a reverse-tunnel from the office, using autossh and a systemd unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Call home using port 2223 and reverse tunnel 22222 into 22
After=network.target

[Service]
User=atilla
Environment="AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -p 2223 -N -R 22222:localhost:22 atilla@my_home_ip

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On my homeserver, I can do `ssh -p 22222 localhost` and connect to the office server. However, when at home, doing `ssh -p 22222 homeserver.local`, the connection gets refused. I always have to log into homeserver and do another hop.

The office server uses latest Raspbian, homeserver is on Ubuntu 22.04, all default settings.

Comment: With just a port specification, it's only listening on localhost. You'll have to use `0.0.0.0:22222` to have it listen on all ports, but then any thing in your home network can connect to it

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1566917/432690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading about `autossh` I see that aside from a few flags, "*all other arguments are passed to ssh*". The specification for the `ssh -R` flag is shown in the manpage with `man ssh`:

> ```
> -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
> ```

In your configuration you've (quite reasonably) omitted the optional `bind_address:` part so the bind is only available to the local machine. Include the colon and an undefined `bind_address` becomes the wildcard `*`, which makes the port accessible from anywhere (subject to firewalls, routing, and other network management layers).

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -p 2223 -N -R *:22222:localhost:22 atilla@my_home_ip
```

You may also need to read up on and change the setting of `GatewayPorts` for the `sshd` service. By default its value is `no`, which prevents you doing what I've just described. See `man sshd_config` for details including the alternative options `yes` and `clientspecified`. Don't choose a value without reading up about it.

---

Having answered this, I should point out that by having an unmanaged ingress into your office network may well be a breach of IT Policy and could result in disciplinary proceedings. Particularly for a route that's about to be accessible from "anywhere".

Answer (score 1):

For sake of completeness, I am sharing another solution I found: using a feature called SSH jump host.

With the above ssh tunnel, this command can connect to the office server in a single go

```
ssh -J homeuser@homeserver:22 -p 22222 workuser@localhost
```

The `-J` flag tells to use user@server:port account as the jump host, and the later are SSH arguments from the point of the jump host.